# Space Shuttle missions for satellite deployment?

Tags: space-shuttle, payload

Was there any Space Shuttle mission whose primary target were e deploying satellites (space stations do not count).

Comment: Do you mean no science was performed, only a satellite payload was deployed?

Comment: I understand such missions do not exist so I modified the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These early missions launched comsats for paying customers.

STS-5, 7, 8, 41-B, 41-D, 51-A, 51-D, 51-G, 51-I, 61-B, 61-C, 49

These missions launched geosynchronous comsats for NASA or other government agencies

STS-6, 26, 29, 32, 43, 54, 51, 70

These missions launched Earth-orbiting scientific or unclassified defense satellites for NASA or other government agencies

STS-41C, 41-G, 61-A, 31, 37, 48, 44, 46, 52, 53, 60, 63, 93

The payloads on several DOD dedicated missions remain classified.

This list does not include

- satellites deployed from the shuttle and retrieved *during the same
  mission*.
- tiny satellites for universities, etc., as Getaway Specials or other
  add-on payloads.
- [planetary probes deployed from shuttle](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40710/6944)

Reference: [Space Shuttle Missions Summary](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110001406/downloads/20110001406.pdf)

Comment: I prefer to change the question then, to ask about primary missions

Comment: STS-32 was also used to retrieve a satellite but this is a nice list of STS satellite launches. I will change the question to match the answer list

Comment: @JoeJobs I did not include missions with only retrievals, since your question asks about *deployments*